# Get values with no repeated data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
      P.LegacyKey
      ,D.DesignNumber
      FROM tbl1 AS [SO]
 GROUP BY D.DesignNumber,P.LegacyKey
 ORDER BY LegacyKey
```

it returning values like:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| LegacyKey | DesignNumber |
+-----------+--------------+
|     17134 |            1 |
|     17134 |            2 |
|     18017 |            7 |
+-----------+--------------+
```

That I want to do is to find duplicate `LegacyKeys` and get only values who legacyKey is exist one time, so I use `HAVING COUNT`:

```
SELECT
      P.LegacyKey
      ,D.DesignNumber
      , COUNT([P].[LegacyKey])
      FROM tbl1 AS [SO]
 GROUP BY D.DesignNumber,P.LegacyKey
 HAVING COUNT([P].[LegacyKey])  = 1
 ORDER BY LegacyKey
```

But this is returning bad data, because it is returning LegacyKey = 17134 again and desire result is to get values where LegacyKey exists one time.

So desire result should be only

```
  18017 |            7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first query has three output columns but your result set only shows two. Something isn't right there.

Comment: Sorry, fixed @SEarle1986

Comment: Dose tbl1 have a primary key then do an inner select :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
SELECT P.LegacyKey, MAX(D.DesignNumber) as DesignNumber
FROM tbl1 AS [SO]
GROUP BY P.LegacyKey
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT D.DesignNumber) = 1;
ORDER BY LegacyKey;
```

No subquery is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
select t2.LegacyKey, t2.DesignNumber
from
(
    select t.LegacyKey 
    from tbl1 t
    group by t.LegacyKey 
    having count(t.LegacyKey ) = 1
)x
join tbl1 t2 on x.LegacyKey = t2.LegacyKey
```

or

```
select t2.LegacyKey, t2.DesignNumber
from tbl1 t2
where t2.LegacyKey in
(
    select t.LegacyKey 
    from tbl1 t
    group by t.LegacyKey 
    having count(t.LegacyKey ) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

NB - This is untested

```
SELECT  *   
FROM    (
            SELECT
                  P.LegacyKey AS LegacyKey,
                  D.DesignNumber AS DesignNumber,
                  COUNT([P].[LegacyKey]) AS cnt
             FROM tbl1 AS [SO]
             GROUP BY D.DesignNumber,P.LegacyKey
             HAVING COUNT([P].[LegacyKey])  = 1
        ) a
WHERE   COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY LegacyKey) = 1
```